# Change .php URL with id into .html

Tags: php, html, url-routing

Given the PHP URL `course.php?id=10` I want it to redirect to `course.html` and I want to use the `id=10` on this page. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can't cleanly rewrite the url and not include the variable somewhere. You'll need to do something like so:

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/([^.]+)\.html $2.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Which will work for `http://example.com/10/course.html`.

Answer (score 1):

Create a `.htaccess` file and add the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)\.html$ $1.php [L]
```

Upload this to the root of your files (most of the time it's `/var/www/` or `/home/user/public_html/`.

Comment: It won't use the GET variable though.

Comment: You shouldn't advice/suggest what paths are used on a server, there is no way you can tell him this. You can however suggest how to find this path (by uploading a file to your webroot and use `get_include_path()` for instance). I for instance have used `/data/www/`, `/data/web/` or `var/projects/` for development. What is common for shared hosting is `/var/www/<account-identifier>/<website-identifier/htdocs/` and endless variations on that. If you work with xampp on windows they will suggest to put it somewhere like `C:\xampplite\htdocs\`. So, just don't suggest anything.