# How to execute php files with .html extension?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, webserver

i have problem with my site, when i try to convert php to html, i got this error
**Not Found**

and this is .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php$ /ver1/$1.html [R=301,QSA,L]
```

all files in folder ver1

i see this post

[.php url to .html url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8562724/php-url-to-html-url)

but not work with me

i just need convert php to html and if i go to index.php

i go to index.html and make all url html

Comment: What do you mean by "convert php to html" ?

Comment: You're doing this backwards. If you want people to be able to access "index.html" and have it execute "index.php", you need to rewrite ".html" to ".php".

Comment: Is the .htaccess file being read? Do you have AllowSymLinks set?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change .php URL with id into .html](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10413777/change-php-url-with-id-into-html) and a million other rewrite questions

Comment: just change links and rewrite url

Answer (score 4):

Rename your .php file to .html and add this line in your .htaccess

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .html .htm
```

Comment: Wow really? "Just rename every file in your site and re-factor your code to fix all the includes... it's easy"  You have to be kidding...

Comment: This code will parse HTML files as PHP - http://www.velvetblues.com/web-development-blog/how-to-parse-html-files-as-php/

Comment: Apologies for 'all your .php files' - rename only the files which you need to parse..

Comment: Sure this is the right way - but if he only had one or two files he would have done that already - the fact that he is looking for a solution this complicated would tend to imply he has alot of .php files he would have to rename . Also he still needs to refactor his code to fix any links or forms if he does what you suggest  - which  could involved some major code updating

Answer (score 0):

You need to add /ver1/ in both places - "^(.*).php$"  -> "^/ver1/(.*).php$"

But that line just turns off the .php version - you never copied the line that tells it to actually serve the PHP files under the different extension (RewriteRule ^(.*).html$ $1.php)

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^/ver1/(.*)\.html$ /ver1/$1.php
RewriteRule ^/ver1/(.*).php$ /ver1/$1.html [R=301,QSA,L]
```

The first rule will internally map .html to .php files and serve them directly to the client

The second rule will REDIRECT anything .php under /ver1/ to it's .html equivalent for SEO purposes

**Edit** - **Warning** - if you have any HTML forms that are action=POST data - you MUST update their action to point to the .html version - otherwise they will stop working (POST data is not redirected!)

Comment: i use

RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^/ver1/(.*)\.html$ /ver1/$1.php
RewriteRule ^/ver1/(.*).php$ /ver1/$1.html [R=301,QSA,L]

url not convert and move to html

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for "How do I rewrite .php to .html using .htaccess rules"????????????????

If yes, use

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /ver1/$1.php [nc]
```

Comment: Still wrong - all his code is in /ver1/ folder so you are telling it do this - "/ver1/file.html" ->  "/ver1/ver1/file.php"

Comment: i not need change ext for all files and samo files pure php

and i test this 

RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /ver1/$1.php [nc]

but url not change like vb.php not direct vb.html

Answer (score 0):

Try it on .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /$1.php
```

Answer (score -1):

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1.php [nc]
```